# Visual Studio compile - Change DLL File Description

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a .NET 4.0 ASP.NET WebApp Project with the following AssemblyInfo.cs:

```
#if(Development)
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("Development")]
#elif(Test)
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("Test")]
#elif(Production)
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("Production")]
#endif
```

After I compiled the project in Visual Studio 2012, I checked the "File Description" property in the Details tab of the Windows Properties dialog for a file and it is empty. How can I set the File Description?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to apply the [`[AssemblyTitle]` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assemblytitleattribute?view=net-7.0).

Answer (score 1):

For .NET projects, you can use the same `AssemblyTitle` attribute but with another way

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <AssemblyTitle>Description of the Assembly goes here</AssemblyTitle>
</PropertyGroup>
```

[image]

MsBuild will automatically add this attribute for you in the generated `AssemblyInfo.cs` file

[image]